# Examples of Epenthesis in Chinese

Tags: pronunciation

**Epenthesis** is a process that inserts a syllabic or non-syllabic segment within an existing string of segments. For example, it is common in casual speech for English speakers to insert a (p) in between [m] and [θ] when pronouncing "warmth" /morm(p)θ/. I am wondering if Mandarin has epenthetic sounds as well, and hopefully someone can give me some examples and reference.

Answer (score 3):

I cannot think of any epenthesis (增音) examples in Mandarin, but it exists in some dialects of Chinese. Here are some examples in Beijing dialect, from this webpage: [教育部语言文字应用研究所 - 普通话语音和北京语音的界限](http://yys.moe.edu.cn/81/peixun05_4.htm).

1) 增加声母：

> 这儿 “儿” er-her
>   女儿 nǚ'er-nǚher （或变为nǚhuor）

2) 增加韵尾：

> 把水倒净 “把” bǎ-bǎi
>   闭上嘴 “闭” bì-bìn
>   枳棘 “棘” ji-jin
>   八下里（各方面） “下”xià-xiàn
>   告诉 “诉” su-song

3) 增加介音：

> 一般儿大（同样大） “般” bān-biān
>   动撼（动） “撼” han-huan（或更变hun）
>   凑合 “合” he-huo

I think the third case is close to what you are looking for (though it's a dialect but not Mandarin), where additional segments are inserted between initials and finals.

**Relevant experiences**

I've met many people who will possibly do a similar thing due to they find it hard to pronounce some particular words in a standard way. However, even they know they are inserting syllables, some of them still think that they are speaking Mandarin rather than a dialect. But who can tell? I have no idea how to clearly draw the line.